# WP Editor Issue in Backend

Tags: plugin-development, editor, wp-editor, plugin-tinymce

I am stuck on silly issue of wp_editor function in WordPress backend in custom plugin page. See issue for wp_editor in attached images

[image]

I have called the wp_editor function like this

```
<?php
  wp_editor(
    stripslashes($item['custom_redirect_message']),
    "custom_redirect_message",
    array(
      "wpautop" => false,
      "name" => "custom_redirect_message",
      "textarea_rows" => 20
    )
  );
?>
```

There is also some js error in console in live environment when I click on link button in editor.

[image]

The link button should not pop out like this.

Any help in this highly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:-

When I check in console there is error. See screenshot attached below

[image]

Again I checked the loading js and found that it is conflict with autocomplete.js which is wordpress default js.

Blocking in browser will resolve the issue but don't know how to figure out and where to change.

Thanks again.

Comment: what do you use to create the tabs ?

Comment: @Kaperto This form has a large fields and different section. So I have divided in multi tabs.